Need to create recursive conversion function or stored procedure in SQL server for population
I am working with a population of items that goes through conversions from 1 type to another based on percentages in a table.
The conversion hapen iteratively until there are conversions left.
What i would like to be able to do input a type and population and return a table of the converted population.
I'm really looking for ideas on how to approach this (using SQL Server).  I'll give a simple example below.
CREATE TABLE populationChanges 
(
    id INT, 
    originaltype VARCHAR(50),
    NewType VARCHAR(50),
    percentOfPopulation DECIMAL(5,4)
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[populationChanges] (id, [originaltype],[NewType], [percentOfPopulation])
VALUES (1, 'trout', 'bass', 0.4000),
       (2, 'trout', 'shark',0.6000),
       (3, 'shark', 'clownFish', 0.3000),
       (4, 'shark', 'PufferFish', 0.7000),
       (5, 'PufferFish', 'Tuna', 0.7000),
       (6, 'PufferFish', 'Coy', 0.1000),
       (7, 'PufferFish', 'Shrimp', 0.2000),
       (8, 'coy', 'lobster', 1.0000),
       (9, 'Shrimp', 'King Crab', 0.6000)

For example if I start with 1000 Shrimp since there is only 1 conversion it simply would return 600,'Lobster', but if there are multiple conversions I need to go through multiple steps
For example: 1000 puffer fish becomes 700 tuna, 100 coy and 200 shrimp, but the coy and shrimp go through another conversion so what a really end up with is
700 tuna, 
100 lobster, 
120 shrimp

My actual data has thousands of types and and up to 20 layers of conversions, and I can't wrap my head around where to start.
Any help would be appreciated

(1) Check your post for accuracy: Do 1000 shrimp become 600 lobster or 600 king crab? Does the second example end up with 120 shrimp or 120 king crab?  (2) Do your conversions eventually reach a terminal static state, or are there feedback loops such that the conversions continue, but might potentially approach some steady state or cyclic state?

How do you know what order to do the conversions? Do you want every possible route to convert a quantity?

You can use recursive CTE like this.
CREATE TABLE #populationChanges 
(
    id INT, 
    originaltype VARCHAR(50),
    NewType VARCHAR(50),
    percentOfPopulation DECIMAL(5,4)
)

INSERT INTO #populationChanges (id, [originaltype],[NewType], [percentOfPopulation])
VALUES (1, 'trout', 'bass', 0.4000),
       (2, 'trout', 'shark',0.6000),
       (3, 'shark', 'clownFish', 0.3000),
       (4, 'shark', 'PufferFish', 0.7000),
       (5, 'PufferFish', 'Tuna', 0.7000),
       (6, 'PufferFish', 'Coy', 0.1000),
       (7, 'PufferFish', 'Shrimp', 0.2000),
       (8, 'coy', 'lobster', 1.0000),
       (9, 'Shrimp', 'King Crab', 0.6000)

declare @orig varchar(50) = 'PufferFish'
,@initVal int = 1000

;with fish as (
--anckor query
select id,originaltype,NewType,cast(percentOfPopulation as float) percentOfPopulation, 1 lvl
from #populationChanges
where originaltype= @orig
union all
--recursive query
select p.id,p.originaltype,p.NewType,p.percentOfPopulation * f.percentOfPopulation, lvl+1 
from #populationChanges p
inner join fish f on p.originaltype=f.NewType
)
select percentOfPopulation * @initVal val, NewType
from fish f
--filter out intermediates
where not exists (select 1 from fish f1 where f.NewType=f1.originaltype)

drop table #populationChanges

Result.
700 Tuna
120 King Crab
100 lobster

I think shrimp in OP expected result is a mistake / typo.
